# Core 2 duo desktop, but taskman and perfmon only report one cpu

Tags: windows, cpu, intel-core2

I have a core 2 duo desktop, but in taskman i can only see one panel in the performance tab, where i'm certain there should be two. Also, in perfmon, under Processor -> % Processor Time, there is only "_Total" and "0" instance.

Am i missing some dual code driver or something?
Thanks

Here's my results from Intels PID, which says that i have a core 2 duo:

```
Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility
Version: 4.10.20090310
Time Stamp: 2009/08/17 02:06:26
Number of processors in system: 1
Current processor: #1
Active cores per processor: 2
Disabled cores per processor: 0
Processor Name: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E6300 @ 1.86GHz
Type: 0
Family: 6
Model: F
Stepping: 2
Revision: 51
Maximum CPUID Level: A
L1 Instruction Cache: 2 x 32 KB
L1 Data Cache: 2 x 32 KB
L2 Cache: 2 MB
Packaging: LGA775
Enhanced Intel SpeedStep(R) Technology: Yes
MMX(TM): Yes
Intel(R) SSE: Yes
Intel(R) SSE2: Yes
Intel(R) SSE3: Yes
Intel(R) SSE4: No
Enhanced Halt State: Yes
Execute Disable Bit: Yes
Intel(R) Hyper-Threading Technology: No
Intel(R) 64 Architecture: Yes
Intel(R) Virtualization Technology: Yes
Expected Processor Frequency: 1.86 GHz
Reported Processor Frequency: 1.86 GHz
Expected System Bus Frequency: 1066 MHz
Reported System Bus Frequency: 1066 MHz
*************************************************************
```

edit2: Here's my boot.ini:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=3
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect
```

edit3: Under Device manager -> 'Computer', i have 'Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC', it doesn't say anything about multiprocessing.

edit4: This would explain how things got in this state: I originally had a single-core PC. To upgrade, i removed my hard drive and put it into this newer, dual core PC. Seems like the drivers didn't automatically upgrade.

edit5: In the end, it was the wrong HAL that was causing the problem, i followed the instructions here to solve it: http://www.handaware.com/multiprocessor_XP.html

Comment: Do you know what motherboard you have?

Comment: No, how can i find out?

Comment: How about using 'Everest' ? http://www.filehippo.com/download_everest_home/

Comment: Bugger, Everest won't work if you're in a domain - crippleware!

Comment: If it helps, its a Hewlett-Packard DC7700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you check which version of the Windows XP hardware abstraction layer your system is using? To do this, run `devmgmt.msc`, look at what item is displayed as the child of "Computer" in the tree, and add this info to your question: "ACPI Multiprocessor PC", "ACPI Uniprocessor PC", "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC", "Standard PC", etc.

If you're not using the "ACPI Multiprocessor PC" HAL, then it sounds like either Sysprep (oops, [this won't work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828287/)) or an in-place upgrade is in order. Here's a knowledgebase explaining [How to perform an in-place upgrade (reinstallation) of Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315341).

Comment: Under 'Computer', i have 'Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC'.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't say anything about 'multiprocessor' anywhere.

Comment: An in-place upgrade should select the ACPI multiprocessor HAL, but then again, the original installation should have as well. I'm curious about how it got in this state. Was this the pre-loaded Windows installation from HP? Did you upgrade CPUs or move a Windows installation from one PC to another? Was this a Windows 2000->XP upgrade?

Comment: I removed my (boot) hard drive from another PC and put it in this PC, which would explain the driver issues...

Comment: I followed these instructions and avoided a full re-install. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

http://www.handaware.com/multiprocessor_XP.html

Answer (score 2):

Run this and make sure you didn't get ripped off(there has been instances of people being sold reboxed/labelled CPUs):
http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/

Make sure it is a Intel Core 2 **Duo**, and not just an Intel Core 2.

Have you overclocked this chip at all?

In the Processes tab, if you right click a process and click "Set Affinity..." are there two check boxes enabled?

In your BIOS see if there is anything fishy with CPU temps, or any other health indicators.

See this if you're running Vista:
http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/153125-boot-advanced-options-number-processors.html

Edit: there may also be options to enable cores in your BIOS

Edit2: In Win XP, right click on "My Computer" -> Properties -> Advanced -> Startup & Recovery;

Click "edit" to edit the Windows Boot.ini file manually.  Make sure it doesn't contain something like /numproc=1 or /ONECPU

Under Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Computer Management->Device Manager->Processors-> You should see two processors listed here. (I have the Core 2 Duo e6400 listed twice)

I saw one post where someone said they had a 4 core processor, and it listed only two cores under Device Manager, so they deleted those two cores here, and let windows reinstall drivers for the new CPU(apperently they had changed CPUs.  This however was on Vista.)  I would be scared to do this though.  **I would first try finding updated drivers for my motherboard chipset.**

Comment: I'm running XP. I've just tried the intel PIU, and posted the results to my question. It says i have a core 2 duo. Not overclocked. There is no option for 'set affinity' in taskman. I'll try looking in the BIOS later and tell you how i go.

Comment: In device manager->processors, i can see 2 instances of "Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU  6300 @ 1.86GHz"

Comment: I went into my BIOS setup and could find nothing about enabling/disabling CPU cores

Answer (score 1):

I haven't a Windows computer to check right now but I remembre that, at least on Windows 2003, there is a préférence somewhère in thé task manager to show graph as if there were only one cpu.

You may also want to look at the bios settings to be sure that thé cpu is correctly recognized and that both Core are enabled.

Also check properties from "My Computer" on the Windows desktop

Comment: Windows Task Manager ... try View > CPU History > One Graph per CPU

Comment: Checked there, it is already set to 'one graph per cpu'. Any other ideas?